# Convert the_permalink() function output into string

Tags: php, functions

How can I convert functions like the_permalink() into strings like $permalink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function which returns a value instead of printing it.

**Example -**

```
$permalink = get_permalink($id); //$id if using outside loop
```